# OpenGL textures not loading with SOIL

Tags: opengl, freeglut, soil

Hey I can't get my texture to show up and I have no idea what's wrong. Tutorials haven't helped. Here's my code:

```
Player p();


//The glutDisplayFunc();
void display() {

glPushMatrix();

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

//Load png with SOIL
playerTex = loadTex("Data/Sprites/player.png");
p.draw();

glFlush();
glPopMatrix(); }


//Load texture
GLuint loadTex(const char* c) {
GLuint temp = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(
    c,
    SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
    SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
    SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT
    );

if (0 == temp)
{
    printf("SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result());
    //return 0;
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, temp);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

return temp; }


//Player object's draw function
void player::draw() {

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex2f(x, y);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(x + spriteW, y);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex2f(x + spriteW, y + spriteL);
glEnd();}
```

spriteX = 0, spriteY = 0, spriteW = 400, spriteL = 400, x = 0, y = 0

This is the output I get:
[Output Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Qw9.jpg)

As you can see the BLACK triangle shows up fine, but with no texture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture coordinates should be in the range 0..1, they are not texel coordinates.  Divide by the texture width and height to convert from texel coordinates to texture coordinates.

You also have the color set to black with the following line:

```
glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
```

Don't do that.  Use white (or change `TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`, but that doesn't seem necessary).

```
glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
```

The color is multiplied by the texture color.  You might as well move it outside the `glBegin()` `glEnd()` block:

```
glColor(1, 1, 1);
glBegin(...);
    ...
glEnd();
```

Comment: I fixed that now in the code, but nothing's changed :/

Comment: I did a test where I just put in 0 and 1 values, I put it in the code above as well

Comment: You have it set to black: `glColor3f(0, 0, 0)`.  Set it to white.